# Upgrading ghc to 7.0.3 breaks wai-handler-devel

Tags: haskell, ghc, yesod

I'm developing a web app on Yesod framework, using wai-handler-devel to run the server.

A `pacman -Syu` (on Arch Linux) upgraded ghc from 7.0.2 to 7.0.3 and now the server throws an exception.

```
$ wai-handler-devel 3000 App.Controller withAppSimple
Attempting to interpret your app...
wai-handler-devel: /usr/lib/ghc-7.0.2/package.conf.d/package.cache:
openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

After a bit of digging I realized that the file existed in `/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.3/package.conf.d/`, so I renamed that folder to `ghc-7.0.3` in the hopes that that would at least temporarily solve the problem (until our Haskell-guy comes back from holiday).

Any suggestion on where to even begin would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I mean I renamed the folder to `ghc-7.0.2` of course. =/

Comment: I'm not familiar with the wai-handler-devel (beyond a 4 minute intro) but once you install a new OS shouldn't you just `cabal install wai-handler-devel`?  If you don't know, just give it a try.

Comment: I think Thomas is right, but you should also `cabal install yesod`. Whenever you upgrade GHC, you need to complete rebuild the package database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to re-install *all* your packages when you upgrade a ghc version (not just wai-handler-devel). You may as well delete all the old ones.

Comment: Each GHC version keeps its packages in a separate directory (usually `.ghc/$ARCH-$VER/`).  It is unnecessary to delete the old directory, it will just go unused (note, however, that wai-handler-devel is a binary and not just a GHC library)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I eventually did as well. I didn't realize this was a necessity. Good thing a re-install is so easy. Thanks everyone. :-)